# estimates for tensors using local coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

Suppose that we have a Kähler manifold $(M, \omega_0)$ and another $(1,1)$ form $\eta$ on $M$. Let $\varphi$ be a smooth function such that $\omega_{\varphi} = \omega_0 + i \partial \bar \partial \varphi$ is positive.  Denote the metric tensor of $\omega_0$ by $g_{i \bar j}$ and $g_0^{i \bar j} = \delta_{i j}$, first derivative of $g_0$ vanishes and $\partial_{i} \bar \partial_{j} \varphi = \varphi_{i \bar j}= \varphi_{i \bar i}$ if $i = j$ and $0$ if $ i \neq j$.

My question is about how to properly estimate tensorial quantity in local coordinates:

For instance if we look at and $\sum_{i}\frac{R_{i  \bar i j \bar k} \varphi_{j} \varphi_{\bar k}}{1+\varphi_{i \bar i}}$, one can estimate:

$\sum_{i}\frac{R_{i  \bar i j \bar k} \varphi_{j} \varphi_{\bar k}}{1+\varphi_{i \bar i}} \geq -C |\partial \varphi|^2 \sum_{i} \frac{1}{1+\varphi_{i \bar i}}$

where $R_{i \bar i j \bar k} = -\partial_{j} \partial_{\bar k} g_{i \bar i} + g^{p \bar q}\partial_{j} g_{i \bar q} \partial_{\bar k} g_{p \bar i}$

1). How to make sense of this $C$ here? Is it coming from the bound on $|R_{i \bar i j \bar k}|$? I do not think it make sense to give bounds to individual component function of tensors which is not invariant under coordinate change.

2). In normal coordinates $R_{i \bar i j \bar k}$ only depends on mixed second derivative of the metric tensor, but in the usual coordinates it also depends on the inverse of the metric tensor and the first derivative of the metric tensor. What is really the dependence on $\omega_0$?

The bounty is about to expire, anyone interested in answering?

Comment: Your local coordinates are totally dependent upon $\omega_0$.

Comment: Yes, but when doing calculations it seems to be easy to neglect that because $\omega_0$ in local coordinates becomes $1$.

Comment: The fact that you forget where the local coordinates come from doesn't make $C$ independent of $\omega_0$. :)

Comment: I updated the question, and is it possible that you might know the explanation? @TedShifrin